Necessary async-await working with IndexedDB
I have a react typescript App, in my App I use IndexedDB for storing some Data.
I have separate class for working with IndexedDB call DB . in one of my class methods I use this code for getting all data
 public async getAll(){

 const promise = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    const req = this.openDB();
    req.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
      console.log("error ", e);
      reject ("error");
    });

    req.addEventListener("success", () => {
      const db = req.result;
      const tx = db.transaction("tasks", "readonly");
      tx.addEventListener("complete", () => {
        console.log("transaction complete");
        db.close();
      });

      const readObj = tx.objectStore("tasks");
      const data = readObj.getAll();
      
      data.addEventListener("success",(e)=>{
        console.log(data);
        console.log(e);
        resolve (data.result);
      });

    });
 });

 return await promise;

} 

and in one of my component event handler
      const db = new DB();
      const dataPro = db.getAll();
      dataPro.then((resData)=>{
      console.log(resData); // I have Data I need it
                           }

but the getAll func works fine without async-await , so my question  is : is it really Necessary to use async-await in  getAll func ?? I mean is there any situation that I need async-await
I try getAll func code  without async-await and it works fine for me

The async and await keywords are essentially "syntactic sugar" for working with Promises in a cleaner way.  They're not necessary, but are very often useful.  However, if all the function does is create and return a Promise then there's little use for them.
The usage shown is even already redundant.  You're awaiting the same Promise twice.  Once here:
const promise = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

And once here:
return await promise;

And since the function is async, you still need to await (or follow with a callback) when calling it:
dataPro.then((resData)=>{

As you're observing, this is all very redundant and unneccessary.  If the function itself doesn't internally await anything then it doesn't need to be async.  It can just return the created Promise:
public getAll(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    // the rest of the code in the Promise
  });
}

And the usage of the function wouldn't change.
If the vendor provides a Promise-based API then you can use that and the async and await keywords can help make the code much simpler and easier to reason about.  If they don't then wrapping otherwise asynchronous operations (with callbacks/events/etc.) in a manual Promise and returning that so consuming code can optionally make use of async and await (as you're doing here) is a common pattern.
